# Capturing POST payload in Dynatrace AppMon 6.5

Tags: dynatrace

​I am using AppMon 6.5 to monitor an application running in Oracle Weblogic with an Apache server as web server.

The clients perform a lot of HTTP POST requests with json payload and I would like to capture the sent data.

I have configured Web Server sensor (Apache agent) to capture all request headers and request parameters and the Servlet sensor (Weblogic agent) to capture all request headers, request parameters, session attributes...

But I am able to capture only the POST parameters when the clients send the parameters as form-data (e.g. login request consists in two post parameters sent as form-data)

The documentation of Web server sensor states this

```
Request Parameter Capturing

Capturing the request parameter has some limitations on the web server:

Only the first 20.000 characters of the combined string of query and POST body will be analyzed. Parameters which are beyond that limit cannot be captured.
Reading request parameters from the POST body is only supported for IIS7+ and Apache based web servers.
```

https://community.dynatrace.com/community/display/DOCDT65/Web+Server+Sensor

Is it not possible to capture the POST data sent as body (e.g json content)??

Thanks in advance

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Dynatrace AppMon does not capture Payload data, it would cause a high overhead. For almost all situations you can get the information you want another way though, e.g. via method arguments.